# htaccess for restful apis with sub directories not working

Tags: .htaccess

I have a directory structure for my apis as:

```
api/
   cameras/
      index.php
      ...
      .htaccess
   bar/
      set/
         index.php
      scan/
         index.php
      retrieve/
         index.php
      list/
         index.php
```

Before I added the bar folder I had this working with my .htaccess folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

I then added this to make it work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule bar/set/(.*) bar/set/index.php [L]
RewriteRule bar/scan/(.*) bar/scan/index.php [L]
RewriteRule bar/list/(.*) bar/list/index.php [L]
RewriteRule bar/retrieve/(.*) bar/retrieve/index.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

They all work except the first one in the list `set`. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the order of your conditions might be causing an issue. Without seeing the URL's you are using I would have to assume. However `RewriteCond` only applies to the rule directly following it. You put the new rules between the conditions and your original rule. Change the order and try it this way and see how it works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteRule ^bar/set/(.*)$ bar/set/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^bar/scan/(.*)$ bar/scan/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^bar/list/(.*)$ bar/list/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^bar/retrieve/(.*)$ bar/retrieve/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteCond` only gets applied to next `RewriteRule`. Try this code instead:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(bar)/(scan|set|scan|retrieve)/(.*)$ $1/$2/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Nice clean implementation. I will use this! Thanks.